# Take first n records from dataframe grouped by unique id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I have my Dataset like this

[image]

As you see is ordered by rating and userId I need to get a new Dataframe with only the top 2 results of each group by unique user_id I've tried to

```
dataframe.groupBy("user_id").agg(someUdfFuntion)
```

I tried to use rank function but it seems not to work,I tried to filter the dataframe but no result how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

val window = Window.partitionBy("userId").orderBy($"rating".desc)

dataframe.withColumn("r", row_number.over(window)).where($"r" <= n)
```

Comment: man plz last question how can I do this same thing but applying a filter to every partition?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean I need the same thing but instead of reducing by a n number I need to filter every group that is contained in a Seq, lets say.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer that.

Comment: Can you just share the python version of the same.